# Irreducible but not completely irreducible

Tags: linear-algebra, ds.dynamical-systems, random-walks

Consider a product of i.i.d. $d\times d$ random matrices $A_{i}$
(with $\mathbb{E}\log\left\Vert A_{i}\right\Vert <\infty$).

Let $F:M\times \mathbb R^d\to M\times \mathbb R^d$ be a linear cocycle, i.e. $F(x,v):=(f(x),A(x)v)$, defined by a measurable function $A:M\to GL(d)$ over a measurable map $f:M\to M$ that preserves $\mu.$

A cocycle is irreducible (resp. completely irreducible) if there is no nonzero proper vector subspace $L$ (resp. nonzero finite union $L$ of proper subspaces) such that $A(x)L=L$ for $\mu$ a.e. point.

**Question** could one give an example that is irreducible but not completely irreducible?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\{1,2\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $A_{1}=\mathrm{diagonal}(2,\frac{1}{2})$, $A_{2}=\mathrm{antidiagonal}(1,1)$.

The cocycle is irreducible but not completely irreducible.